# How to send multiple value in a enumeration field with soapUi

Tags: soapui

I'm testing a webservice request with SoapUI.

I have a string that acts as a filter that is bitwise in my request. 
The field is an enumeration for SoapUI.  In the XSD I have all enumeration values.

I need to be able to send 2 or more enumeration values in the fields but SoapUI only accepts the text, for example "All" or "testvalue2."  I would like to send testvalue and testvalue2 for example.

Thanks for you help

XSD extract :

```
<xs:enumeration value="None">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">0</EnumerationValue>
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="Testvalue">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">1</EnumerationValue>
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="Testvalue2">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">2</EnumerationValue>
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="All">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">255</EnumerationValue>
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
```

Comment: It has been sometime since you asked this question have you been able to resolve it? There is no restriction in soapUI on what and how enum values will be sent what matters is will the service actually accept multiple enum values sent at the same time, in my experience the service will accept only one value at a time.

Comment: No I didn't resolve the issue, I've been in communication with SoapUi help desk but nothing have come up. We will change our implementation instead.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of how you would enter this value on your website?

Comment: We don't enter directly the value in the website. It's the controller you choose the value depending of the context. It's a way to ask only for object that we need.

Comment: On the UI are you/controller able to submit multiple values for this field? Have you tried to repeat the field something like<a>Testvalue</a><a>Testvalue2</a><a>All</a>?

Comment: Good advice it's working , soapUi don't show it as a array but by the xml I can copy the value. thanks a lot for you help

Comment: In soapUI under WSDL settings there are options like "generate example values","generate type information in new request" and "always include optional schema elements" have them checked and they'll tell you when a set of tags can be repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to duplicate the field instead of entering all value in the field.

```
  <tem:RequestExtendedInfo>
     <!--Optional:-->
  <rxas:ExtendedInfo>testvalue1</rxas:ExtendedInfo>
  <rxas:ExtendedInfo>testvalue2</rxas:ExtendedInfo>
  </tem:RequestExtendedInfo>
```

Thanks to Abhishek Asthana for it's help